# Help with excercise about symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove if any of the sets $(X \backslash Y) \triangle Z$ and $(X \backslash Z) \triangle (Y \backslash Z)$ is a subset of the other. I am trying to get some understanding of these sets by looking what it means for an element to belong to one of them, but instead I am losing myself in logical disjunctions and conjunctions and see no way of solving the problem.

I would like to know if you know some concrete way to solve this.

---

I got the answer guys: none is subset of the other.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Start by looking at simple examples. Take the universe to be the integers from 1 to 10, and try various definitions of X, Y, and Z.

Comment: You may draw Venn diagrams to get some ideas, and use small sets of numbers for $X$,$Y$,$Z$ which contain multiples of different prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

to get a handle on such questions it may sometimes help to use a symbolic calculus based on indicator functions with arithmetic mod $2$. if we indicate symmetric difference by $+$ and use $ab$ for $A \cap B$ then $A'$, the complement of $A$ may be written $1+a$ and:
$$
a + b = (1+a)b + a(1+b)
$$
so
$$
(X \backslash Y) \triangle Z \to x(1+y)(1+z) +(1+x(1+y))z \\
=x+xy +z
$$
and
$$
(X \backslash Z) \triangle (Y \backslash Z) = x(1+z)(1+y(1+z)) +(1+x(1+z))y(1+z) \\
= (x+y)(1+z)
$$
this shows that if $\exists s \in X'\cap Y \cap Z$ then $s$ is in the first set but not the second, whilst if $\exists t \in X \cap Y' \cap Z'$ then such a $t$ is in the second but not the first.